# how to create csv with bash or python from raw report text

Tags: python, bash, csv, parsing, text

my first question here so hopefully I don't screw this up.

I have the following format in a text file, and would need to convert it to a csv file with the following csv format

**UserID, HostName**

Current file format is:

**EDIT**: pasting contents created a space between the 2 lines

```
Users in wheelgroup for hostname.domain.net:
root,jk34,anoo,thak,aeln,gath,kyhe
```

*There are about 50 users in this list*

I've tried the following.

```
cat testfile |grep wheel |awk '{print $5}'
```

which gives me the hostname, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get the line after and parse it

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: @Armali - the blank line must have happened when I pasted in the info. I'll update it

Answer (score 0):

> I've tried the following.
> `cat testfile |grep wheel |awk '{print $5}'` - which gives me the hostname, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get the line after and parse it

You can get the next line - who would have thought ;-) - with [`getline`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline):

```
awk '/wheel/ {hostname=$5; getline after; split(after, users, ","); for (i in users) print users[i]","hostname}'
```

Comment: you rock, exactly what I was looking for.. .thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged [python](/questions/tagged/python), a quick-and-easy Python solution for you:

```
import csv

report = '''Users in wheelgroup for hostname.domain.net:
root,jk34,anoo,thak,aeln,gath,kyhe'''.split("\n")
users = list(map(lambda x: {"UserID": x, "HostName": report[0].split(" ")[4][:-1]}, report[1].split(",")))

with open("csvfile.csv", "w", newline='') as f:
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, users[0].keys())
    w.writeheader()
    w.writerows(users)
```

Side note: this is likely not the most elegant/efficient/"Pythonic" way of doing this, but should get you to where you want to be.

Comment: I also tried this with python, this is awesome thank you!!